# ERC20 approve attack: may its success be dependent on mainer decision about transaction order?

Tags: solidity, erc-20, erc-20-approve

My question is related to the possible attack vector on ERC20 contracts described [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1YLPtQxZu1UAvO9cZ1O2RPXBbT0mooh4DYKjA_jp-RLM/edit). This attack effectively boils down to these steps:

1. First transaction (mined): Alice calls `approve(addressOfBob, N)`
2. Second transaction (not mined yet): Alice calls `approve(addressOfBob, M)`
3. Third transaction (not mined yet): Bob calls `transferFrom(addressOfAlice, myAddress, N)`
4. If the third transaction is mined before the second one, Bob gains a possibility to send yet another transaction where he calls `transferFrom(addressOfAlice, myAddress, M)`

I wonder if the second transaction happens to find itself in *the same block* with the third one, what then should be? Did I get it right that in this case success/failure of the attack pivots on the transaction order the miner voluntarily decided to apply? That is to say, if the second transaction precedes the third one, it would mean a flop for Bob, and vice versa.

Comment: Usually attacks like these are done with a flash loan, so order won’t matter. Once the attacker ‘s transaction gets mined , everything is executed